# How can I conditionally remove rows of a matrix based on values in those rows?

Tags: r, matrix, filtering

I want to remove several entire rows of a matrix based on the values in a row. For example, if I have rows

```
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
```

and row 2 has a 1 in it, I want the output to be:

```
Row 1
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
```

Nothing I've tried works, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a matrix like this -

```
mat <- matrix(c(5, 4, 3, 
         1, 2, 3, 
         5, 6, 7, 
         4, 6, 7), byrow = TRUE, 4, 3)

mat

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    4    3
#[2,]    1    2    3
#[3,]    5    6    7
#[4,]    4    6    7
```

and you want to remove rows which has 1 in any column using `rowSums` you can do -

```
result <- mat[rowSums(mat == 1, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
result

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    4    3
#[2,]    5    6    7
#[3,]    4    6    7
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** See Martin Gal's comment:
Replacing `any(x == 1)` with `all(x != 1)` could save you an `!` in front of `condition`.

Data from Ronak Shah (many thanks!).
We could feed a logical vector with `TRUE` and `FALSE`
and use it for subsetting:

All `1` will be assigned `TRUE` within `condition` -> `[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

To select all rows that are not `1` use `!`

```
condition <- apply (mat, 1, function(x) any(x==1))

mat[!condition,]
```

output:

```
> mat[!condition,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4    3
[2,]    5    6    7
[3,]    4    6    7
```

Comment: Replacing `any(x == 1)` with `all(x != 1)` could save you an `! ` in front of `condition`.  ;-)

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Are you referring to that `pivot` problem? Your solution was way more easy than mine. Actually mine was ridicously complicated, I didn't think of that `.value` option. Don't feel sorry, the better solution earns the reputation. :-)

Comment: Believe me it happens to me all the time to come up with a solution much more verbose, but it's just that the mind may have been occupied with something else. We could all come up with that simple solution. Since you are a dear friend like TarJae I just wanted to reach out and talk to you.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
sbt(mat, !dapply(mat==1, MARGIN = 1, FUN = any))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4    3
[2,]    5    6    7
[3,]    4    6    7
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 2, 6, 6, 3, 3, 7, 7), .Dim = 4:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other base R options (borrow `mat` from [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68704051/12158757))

```
> subset(mat, rowSums(mat == 1) == 0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4    3
[2,]    5    6    7
[3,]    4    6    7

> do.call(rbind, apply(mat, 1, function(x) if (!1 %in% x) x))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4    3
[2,]    5    6    7
[3,]    4    6    7
```